# Is it possible to test a actions on google app on the sdk (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: raspberry-pi, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have made an 'Actions on google' app with api.ai and a webhook. Is there a way for me to add it to the google-assistant-demo running on my pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add it to the google-assistant-demo. If you enable it in the simultor, it will be testable on any Actions on Google enabled devices such as Google Home, Pixel or google-assistant-demo. Make sure they are on the same account.
https://developers.google.com/actions/console/publishing#testing